# switched to mysql from sqlite, unable to migrate databse

Tags: mysql, laravel, sqlite

I was using sqlite and just tried to connect to my Mysql database by

1. changing the env.
2. `php artisan migrate:fresh` 
   **Nothing Happened**

**Here's my .env:-**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=white
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I tried deleting the sqlite file and now it shows me this error :- `Database (/home/kabir/Desktop/White/database/database.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)`

 which is normal

Comment: It seems your app is still trying to connect to the sqlite db, not mysql

Comment: yess.. How do i change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing config and cache files.
In your terminal try

> `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: yess..just found this solution online so I answered my own question. thanks for your reply

Comment: omg, this happened so many times to me
never understood why this happens
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this situation is to run these commands:-

1. `php artisan config:clear`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`